# Return on arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return, arrow-functions

I have this input file that calls `checkSize(e)`:

```
<input type="file" id="file"  accept=".jpg,.jpeg,png" multiple  onChange={(e)=> { handleImageChange(e); checkSize(e) }} />
```

The `checkSize` function works fine:

```
const checkSize = (e) => { 
    if (parseInt(e.target.files[0].size/1024) > 240) {
        document.getElementById("error-file-size").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error-file-size").style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
};
```

But now I need to know if `checkSize` returns `true` or `false`. I try to bring the result as follows:

```
console.log(checkSize);
```

This returns me:

[image]

I understand I should call the function like this, but I don't have the value of `e`:

```
console.log(checkSize(e));
```

How can I know if `checkSize` returns `true` or `false`?

Comment: You can't know if `checkSize` returns true or false without a value of `e`, because that the function returns _depends on that value_.

Answer (score 0):

Call `checkSize(e)` inside of `handleImageChange`.

Something like this:

```
const handleImageChange = (e) => {
   const sizeFit = checkSize(e);
   if (!sizeFit) {
      console.log('Too big');
      return;
   }

   // .... your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your function not depend on the event

```
const checkSize = (size) => size > 240;
```

And use it

```
const checkSizeInput = (e) => { 
    if (checkSize(e.target.files[0].size/1024)) {
        document.getElementById("error-file-size").style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error-file-size").style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
};
```

And test it

```
console.log(checkSize(200));
```

It's the only way to call it the way you want, making it not need the event to work, or you can add the `console.log` inside it, then you will log when using the input